# Jetty error while installing WAR on Fuse

Tags: jetty, osgi, war, apache-karaf, fuseesb

I am trying to install a war(abc.war) file on Fuse using the wrap command in fuse. I run into the following jetty error and not sure if I am missing any jetty seting/configuration.
Posting it here to see if anyone have already faced this and know how to fix.
Appreciate your help.

---------------- Error Stack ----------------------------

```
org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-runtime - 1.1.11 | Unbinding bundle: [file_C__jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024_installables_**abc.war** [244]]
10:34:39,140 | ERROR | Executor: 1      | WebXmlObserver                   | 229 - org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-extender-war - 1.1.11 | Could not parse web.xml
org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.6.7.v20120910 | FAILED **org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler**@19281f6: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LoginService for org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator@48218c in org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@19281f6
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LoginService for org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator@48218c in org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@19281f6
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.LoginAuthenticator.setConfiguration(LoginAuthenticator.java:45)[82:org.eclipse.jetty.security:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:376)[82:org.eclipse.jetty.security:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:233)[82:org.eclipse.jetty.security:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)[90:org.eclipse.jetty.util:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.doStart(ScopedHandler.java:115)[84:org.eclipse.jetty.server:7.6.7.v20120910]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doStart(SessionHandler.java:120)
```

---

---------------------------- jetty config ----------------------------

Location: fuse-Root/etc/jetty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//
DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Set connectors                                              -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- One of each type!                                           -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->

    <!-- Use this connector for many frequently idle connections
         and for threadless continuations.
    -->
    <Call name="addConnector">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <Set name="host">
                    <Property name="jetty.host"/>
                </Set>
                 <!-- default port will be overwritten by pax-web configuration -->
                <Set name="port">
                    <Property name="jetty.port" default="8181"/>
                </Set>
                <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
                <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
                <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
                <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
                <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
                <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>

    <Call name="addBean">
        <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.JAASLoginService">
                <Set name="name">karaf</Set>
                <Set name="loginModuleName">karaf</Set>
                <Set name="roleClassNames">
                    <Array type="java.lang.String">
                        <Item>org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot.principal.RolePrincipal</Item>
                    </Array>
                </Set>
            </New>
        </Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

---

------------------------------------ web.xml ---------------------------------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" metadata-complete="true">
  <display-name>abc</display-name>
  <distributable/>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>
          org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-    class>
   </listener>
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
         <description>Hides the listing of available services when set to true.
            It is considered a security risk to set this to false (or leave it unset),
        because a container should never give more information to the client
        than is necessary to function properly.</description>
       <param-name>hide-service-list-page</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   <login-config>
     <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
   </login-config>
 </web-app>
```

---

------------------------------------ META-INF -----------------------------------------

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0 Bundle-ClassPath: WEB-INF/classes,WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar,WEB-I NF/lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar,WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar,WEB-INF/lib/as m-3.3.1.jar,WEB-INF/lib/aspectjrt-1.6.11.jar,WEB-INF/lib/aspectjweave
r-1.6.11.jar,WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15-1.43.jar,WEB-INF/lib/cglib-2.2. 2.jar,WEB-INF/lib/collections-generic-4.01.jar,WEB-INF/lib/commons-bea nutils-1.8.0.jar,WEB-INF/lib/commons-codec-1.3.jar,WEB-INF/lib/common s-
collections-3.2.1.jar,WEB-INF/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar,WEB-IN F/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar,WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar,WEB- INF/lib/cxf-api-2.2.9.jar,WEB-INF/lib/cxf-common-schemas-2.2.9.jar,WE B-INF/lib/cxf-common-
utilities-2.2.9.jar,WEB-INF/lib/cxf-rt-bindings- soap-2.2.9.jar,WEB-INF/lib/cxf-rt-bindings-xml-2.2.9.jar,WEB-INF/lib/ cxf-rt-core-2.2.9.jar,WEB-INF/lib/cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-2.2.9.jar,W EB-INF/lib/cxf-rt-frontend-
jaxws-2.2.9.jar,WEB-INF/lib/cxf-rt-fronten d-simple-2.2.9.jar,WEB-INF/lib/cxf-rt-transports-http-2.2.9.jar,WEB-I NF/lib/cxf-rt-ws-addr-2.2.9.jar,WEB-INF/lib/cxf-rt-ws-security-2.2.9. jar,WEB-INF/lib/cxf-spring-security-2.3.0.jar,WEB-
INF/lib/cxf-tools-c ommon-2.2.9.jar,WEB-INF/lib/derby-10.8.2.2.jar,WEB-INF/lib/derbyclien t-10.8.2.2.jar,WEB-INF/lib/derbynet-10.8.2.2.jar,WEB-INF/lib/derbytoo ls-10.8.2.2.jar,WEB-INF/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar,WEB-INF/lib/ehcache-core-
2.2.0.jar,WEB-INF/lib/esapi-2.0GA.jar,WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-activation _1.1_spec-1.0.2.jar,WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.ja r,WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec-1.6.jar,WEB-INF/lib/geronimo -
jaxws_2.1_spec-1.0.jar,WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1. jar,WEB-INF/lib/geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.2.jar,WEB-INF/lib/h ibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar,WEB-INF/lib/ibm-xmlschema-5.0.2.jar,WEB -INF/lib/ibm-
xsdbeans-5.0.2.jar,WE B-INF/lib/javaparser-1.0.8.jar,WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar,WEB -INF/lib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar,WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar,WEB-INF/li b/jaxb2-basics-0.6.4.jar,WEB-
INF/lib/jaxb2-basics-runtime-0.6.4.jar,W EB-INF/lib/jaxb2-basics-tools-0.6.4.jar,WEB-INF/lib/jaxp-ri-no-servic es-1.4.3.jar,WEB-INF/lib/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar,WEB-INF/lib/jcl-ove r-slf4j-1.6.1.jar,WEB-INF/lib/joda-time-1.6.jar,WEB-
INF/lib/jsr250-ap i-1.0.jar,WEB-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.6.1.jar,WEB-INF/lib/log4j-1.2.16 .jar,WEB-INF/lib/neethi-2.0.4.jar,WEB-INF/lib/not-yet-commons-ssl-0.3 .9.jar,WEB-INF/lib/opensaml-2.5.1-1.jar,WEB-INF/lib/openws-1.4.2-1.ja r,WEB-
INF/lib/saaj-api-1.3.jar,WEB-INF/lib/saaj-impl-1.3.2.jar,WEB-IN F/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar,WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar,WE B-INF/lib/spring-asm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar,WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-3.1.3 .RELEASE.jar,WEB-
INF/lib/spring-context-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar,WEB-INF/lib /spring-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar,WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-3.1.3.RE LEASE.jar,WEB-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar,WEB-INF/lib/sprin g-ldap-core-1.3.1.RELEASE.jar,WEB-
INF/lib/spring-ldap-core-tiger-1.3. 1.RELEASE.jar,WEB-INF/lib/spring-orm-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar,WEB-INF/lib/sp ring-security-config-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar,WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-co re-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar,WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-
ldap-3.1.3.RELEASE.j ar,WEB-INF/lib/spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar,WEB-INF/lib/spri ng-tx-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar,WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar,WEB- INF/lib/springclaims-client-2.0.jar,WEB-INF/lib/stax-api-1.0-2.jar,WE B-
INF/lib/velocity-1.5.jar,WEB-INF/lib/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar,WEB-INF/lib/w ss4j-1.5.8.jar,WEB-INF/lib/wstx-asl-3.2.9.jar,WEB-INF/lib/xml-resolve r-1.2.jar,WEB-INF/lib/XmlSchema-1.4.5.jar,WEB-INF/lib/xmlsec-1.4.3.ja r,WEB-
INF/lib/xmltooling-1.3.2-1.jar Built-By: I303980 Tool: Bnd-0.0.357 Bundle-Name: file_C__jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024_installables_abc.war Created-By: 1.6.0_38 (Sun Microsystems Inc.) Web-ContextPath: abc WAR-URL: file:C:/jboss-
fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024/installables/abc.war Generated-By-Ops4j-Pax-From: file:C:/jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024/insta llables/abc.war Build-Jdk: 1.6.0 Bundle-Version: 0 Bnd-LastModified: 1374079822484 Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2 Bundle-
SymbolicName: file_C__jboss-fuse-6.0.0.redhat-024_installables_ abc.war Import-Package: javax.crypto;resolution:=optional,javax.crypto.interfaces;resolu tion:=
optional,javax.crypto.spec;resolution:=optional,javax.ejb;resol ution:=optional,javax.el;resolution:=optional,javax.faces.application ;resolution:=optional,javax.faces.component;resolution:=optional,java x.faces.context;resolution:=
optional,javax.faces.el;resolution:=optio nal,javax.faces.event;resolution:=optional,javax.imageio;resolution:= optional,javax.imageio.metadata;resolution:=optional,javax.imageio.st ream;resolution:=optional,javax.inject;resolution:=
optional,javax.int erceptor;resolution:=optional,javax.jdo;resolution:=optional,javax.jd o.datastore;resolution:=optional,javax.jmdns;resolution:=optional,jav ax.jms;resolution:=optional,javax.management;resolution:=optional,jav
ax.management.modelmbean;resolution:=optional,javax.management.openmb ean;resolution:=optional,javax.management.remote;resolution:=optional ,javax.naming;resolution:=optional,javax.naming.directory;resolution: =
optional,javax.naming.event;resolution:=optional,javax.naming.ldap;r esolution:=optional,javax.naming.spi;resolution:=optional,javax.net;r esolution:=optional,javax.net.ssl;resolution:=optional,javax.persiste nce;resolution:=
optional,javax.persistence.spi;resolution:=optional,j avax.portlet;resolution:=optional,javax.resource;resolution:=optional ,javax.resource.cci;resolution:=optional,javax.resource.spi;resolutio n:=
optional,javax.resource.spi.endpoint;resolution:=optional,javax.re source.spi.work;resolution:=optional,javax.rmi;resolution:=optional,j avax.security.auth;resolution:=optional,javax.security.auth.callback; resolution:=
optional,javax.security.auth.login;resolution:=optional,j avax.security.auth.spi;resolution:=optional,javax.security.auth.x500; resolution:=optional,javax.security.cert;resolution:=optional,javax.s ecurity.jacc;resolution:=
optional,javax.servlet,javax.servlet.annotat ion;resolution:=optional,javax.servlet.http,javax.servlet.jsp;resolut ion:=optional,javax.servlet.jsp.el;resolution:=optional,javax.servlet .jsp.tagext;resolution:=
optional,javax.sql;resolution:=optional,javax .sql.rowset;resolution:=optional,javax.swing;resolution:=optional,jav ax.swing.border;resolution:=optional,javax.swing.event;resolution:=op tional,javax.swing.table;resolution:=
optional,javax.swing.text;resolu tion:=optional,javax.swing.tree;resolution:=optional,javax.transactio n;resolution:=optional,javax.transaction.xa;resolution:=optional,java x.validation;resolution:=
optional,javax.validation.bootstrap;resoluti on:=optional,javax.validation.metadata;resolution:=optional,javax.ws. rs.core;resolution:=optional,javax.ws.rs.ext;resolution:=optional,jav ax.xml;resolution:=
optional,javax.xml.datatype;resolution:=optional,j avax.xml.namespace;resolution:=optional,javax.xml.parsers;resolution: =optional,javax.xml.rpc;resolution:=optional,javax.xml.rpc.handler;re solution:=
optional,javax.xml.rpc.handler.soap;resolution:=optional,ja vax.xml.rpc.server;resolution:=optional,javax.xml.rpc.soap;resolution :=optional,javax.xml.transform;resolution:=optional,javax.xml.transfo rm.dom;resolution:=
optional,javax.xml.transform.sax;resolution:=optio nal,javax.xml.transform.stax;resolution:=optional,javax.xml.transform .stream;resolution:=optional,javax.xml.validation;resolution:=optiona l,javax.xml.xpath;resolution:=
optional,org.apache.commons.logging;pro vider=paxlogging;resolution:=optional,org.apache.commons.logging.impl ;provider=paxlogging;resolution:=optional,org.apache.cxf.transport.se rvlet;resolution:=optional,org.apache.log4j;provider=
paxlogging;resol ution:=optional,org.apache.log4j.spi;provider=paxlogging;resolution:= optional,org.apache.log4j.xml;provider=paxlogging;resolution:=optiona l,org.slf4j;provider=paxlogging;resolution:=optional,org.slf4j.helper
s;provider=paxlogging;resolution:=optional,org.slf4j.spi;provider=pax logging;resolution:=optional,org.springframework.web.context;resoluti on:=optional,org.w3c.dom;resolution:=optional,org.w3c.dom.bootstrap;r esolution:=
optional,org.w3c.dom.events;resolution:=optional,org.w3c.d om.html;resolution:=optional,org.w3c.dom.ls;resolution:=optional,org. w3c.dom.ranges;resolution:=optional,org.w3c.dom.traversal;resolution: =
optional,org.w3c.dom.xpath;resolution:=optional,org.xml.sax;resoluti on:=optional,org.xml.sax.ext;resolution:=optional,org.xml.sax.helpers ;resolution:=optional Originally-Created-By: Apache Maven Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

---

Comment: Maybe post your web.xml and your generated manifest.mf

Comment: Hi are you able to fix this issue

Comment: Did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a SecurityConstraint in your web.xml. 
Take a look at the pax-web samples at [war-authentication sample](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.web/blob/master/samples/war-authentication/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L94)